# personal.sendTransaction not broadcasting? (geth)

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to use the `personal.sendTransaction()` method and it returns a valid txid, but looks like it never gets broadcasted to the network. (Can't pick it up on etherscan or any ETH explorers)

I've tried this on both a fast sync and a light sync with no avail.

Transactions do show up using `eth.pendingTransactions`:

```
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x66ec231d3d50fd2c5a9a5242c76d91ca39a79c35",
    gas: 21000,
    gasPrice: 18010524411,
    hash: "0x9367ca24e37184f328a5b9edd67a776f98f2195803a6237d452de2e8f4fb2083",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 5,
    r: "0x7f0e5d712072782ecb5ac39072044229d6283166a182749b0e50adce1224601f",
    s: "0x63c276600b15e7db1543fcb115c30cf94ee0948bbf7ead1200925602428ec54f",
    to: "0x4408f69a5a7ef19c5cf61309a046e735e2e38ea3",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x25",
    value: 1000000000000000
}]
```

I really am at loss of what is going on

I also submitted a issue on the Github here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21167

Comment: Was this transaction send on mainet or testnet?

Comment: It was on the mainnet network

Comment: It does appear in etherscan now. If you look your account it has several pending transactions with very low fee. For several weeks the network has been very congested, so unless you replace them with new transactions with higher fees they will remain stuck.

Comment: @Ismael oh yes I see that now. Is there any way to speed up the process? It did take a fair while to actually reach the network

Comment: You can use Metamask importing the account's private key then you can replace pending transactions by overriding them creating a transaction with the same pending nonce.

Comment: @Ismael Is there a reason behind the transaction taking forever to actually show up in etherscan?

Comment: Etherscan is closed source so we can only speculate is related to the high volume of pending transactions or network congestion.